# typedef equations in C

Tags: c

I have following typedef declarations in c but confused how I read these declarations.

```
   typedef char  *pc;     /* pc is pointer to char                      */
   typedef pc     fpc();  /* fpc is function returning pointer to char  */
   typedef fpc   *pfpc;
   typedef pfpc   fpfpc();
   typedef fpfpc *pfpfpc;
   pfpfpc a[N];
```

Now for me first two statement is easy to read but really confused after that.

Is there any way to solve(read) such equations?

Comment: This might be a good candidate for an obfuscation contest.

Comment: `a` is an array of pointers to function pointers returning a pointer to a function pointer returning a pointer to a `char`. I think I should get some sleep before my I lose my mind over this...

Comment: copy paste from http://c-faq.com/decl/cdecl1.html, downvote.

Comment: I didn't copy it from link you gave here ,its problem taken from a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef char  *pc;     /* pc is pointer to char                      */
typedef pc     fpc();  /* fpc is function returning pointer to char  */
```

Good so far.  Note that the last typedef can also be written as

```
typedef char *fpc();
```

Next,

```
typedef fpc   *pfpc;
```

declares `pfpc` as a pointer to `fpc`.  Since we know that `fpc` is a function returning a pointer to `char`, then `pfpc` must be a pointer to a function returning pointer to `char`, or

```
typedef char *(*pfpc)()
```

Next we have

```
typedef pfpc   fpfpc();
```

This time, `fpfpc` is a function returning `pfpc`.  Since we know that `pfpc` is a pointer to a function returning pointer to `char`, `fpfpc` must be a function returning a pointer to a function returning pointer to `char`, or

```
typedef char *(*fpfpc())();
```

Next, we have

```
typedef fpfpc *pfpfpc;
```

which declares `pfpfpc` as a pointer to `fpfpc`.  Since we know `fpfpc` is a function returning a pointer to a function returning pointer to `char`, pfpfpc must be a pointer to a function returning a pointer to a function returning a pointer to `char`, or

```
typedef char *(*(*pfpfpc)())();
```

Finally, we have an an N-element array of `pfpfpc`

```
pfpfpc a[N];
```

Since we know `pfpfpc` is a pointer to a function returning pointers to functions returning pointers to `char`, then `a` must be an N-element array of pointers to functions returning pointers to functions returning pointers to `char`:

```
char *(*(*a[N])())();
```

The main rule to remember for reading and writing hairy declarations is that `[]` and `()` have higher precedence than `*`, so

```
*a[]       -- is an array of pointer
(*a)[]     -- is a pointer to an array
*f()       -- is a function returning a pointer
(*f)()     -- is a pointer to a function
```

and the whole thing is broken down as

```
          a                -- a
          a[N]             -- is an N-element array
         *a[N]             -- of pointers
        (*a[N])()          -- to functions
       *(*a[N])()          -- returning pointer
      (*(*a[N])())()       -- to function
     *(*(*a[N])())()       -- returning pointer
char *(*(*a[N])())()       -- to char
```

Going the other way, we have

```
         pfpfpc              -- is a synonym for
       *  fpfpc              -- is a synonym for
       *   pfpc()            -- is a synonym for
       *(* fpc)()            -- is a synonym for
       *(*pc())()            -- is a synonym for
char *(*(* )())()
```

The last step isn't terribly intuitive, I'll admit.

Answer (score 1):

```
   typedef char *pc;      // pc is pointer to char
   typedef pc fpc();      // fpc is function accepting unspecified arguments and returning pc
   typedef fpc *pfpc;     // pfpc is pointer to fpc
   typedef pfpc fpfpc();  // fpfpc is function accepting unspecified arguments and returning pfpc
   typedef fpfpc *pfpfpc; // pfpfpc is a pointer to fpfpc
   pfpfpc a[N];           // a is an array of N pfpfpc
```

Better names might be helpful :)
I realize this was example code. In real code use understandable naming conventions.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar `a` is an array of function pointers returning a pointer to a function pointer returning a pointer to a `char`. Did I get that right?

Comment: I read them as in the comments above. I do not read them recursively at all.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the second last one. "pointer to function pointer". (can't edit now.) "`a` is an array of pointers to function pointers returning a pointer to a function pointer returning a pointer to a `char`." This is amusing...

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like the following:

```
    typedef char *pc;           /* pc is pointer to char                     */
    typedef pc fpc();           /* fpc is function taking no arguments returing pointer to char  */
    typedef fpc *pfpc;          /* pfpc is a pointer to a function taking no arguments returning a pointer to a char */
    typedef pfpc fpfpc();       /* fpfpc is a function returning a pointer to a function taking no arguments returning a pointer to a char */
    typedef fpfpc *pfpfpc;      /* pfpfpc is a pointer to a function returning a pointer to a function taking no arguments returning a pointer to a char */
    pfpfpc a[N];                /* a is an array of pointers to functions returning a pointer to a function taking no arguments returning a pointer to a char */
```

In addition to this, take a look at this blog entry, ([http://blog.feabhas.com/2009/12/unscrambling-c-declarations](http://blog.feabhas.com/2009/12/unscrambling-c-declarations/)/)

Comment: want to how you are reading these statements? Any specific way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at the link I just added :) That goes into detail about descrambling C declarations. Once you have a good grasp of that, it's a case of expanding out each `typedef` to include the last.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the "right-left rule"](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) to decipher C declarations in a straightforward and regular way.

> Read
>
> ```
>  *    as "pointer to"         - always on the left side
>  []   as "array of"           - always on the right side
>  ()   as "function returning"     - always on the right side
> ```
>
> as you encounter them in the declaration.
>
> STEP 1: Find the identifier.  This is your starting point.  Then say to yourself, "identifier is."  You've started your declaration.
>
> STEP 2: Look at the symbols on the right of the identifier.  If, say, you find "()" there, then you know that this is the declaration for a
>   function.  So you would then have "identifier is function returning". 
>   Or if you found a  "[]" there, you would say "identifier is array of".
>   Continue right until you run out of symbols *OR* hit a *right*
>   parenthesis ")".  (If you hit a  left parenthesis, that's the
>   beginning of a () symbol, even if there is stuff in between the
>   parentheses.  More on that below.)
>
> STEP 3: Look at the symbols to the left of the identifier.  If it is not one of our symbols above (say, something like "int"), just say it.
>   Otherwise, translate it into English using that table above.  Keep
>   going left until you run out of symbols *OR* hit a *left* parenthesis
>   "(".
>
> Now repeat steps 2 and 3 until you've formed your declaration.

It is also described at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations and http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Classes/03F/cis399/notes/right-left.html.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you declare a variable x of type int:

```
int x;
```

this is how you declare a function f that returns an integer and takes one integer argument:

```
int f(int);
```

This is how you typedef an int

```
typedef int size_t;
```

This is how you typedef a function that returns an integer and takes one integer argument

```
typedef int f_int_int_t(int);
```